# Can we still use max-new-space-size in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Can we still use max-new-space-size in nodejs ?  how does it work ?
if yes then what is the ideal ratio between max-old-space-size and max-new-space-size?
can someone please help me understand this ?

Answer (score 2):

No, that flag does not exist.

There is `--max-semi-space-size`. The best option is to leave it alone. There is no "ideal ratio" between old and new space sizes; their size ratio does not matter.

It's fine to increase the max old space size if you need a bigger heap; there is no reason to change the new space size when you do that.